# Text box is updated in the background but not visually

Tags: c#, web-applications, textbox

Little bit of background; I am creating a Web Application using C# that requires text boxes to be written to and to be read from. The text appears to be getting written to the text box as it is being inserted into queries I need it for however the textbox does not show any of the text.

It works as expected if I add text to the text box during the page load method but due to other errors my button click method creates a new thread to execute the code required. Here is how I create this new thread:

```
        Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(threadMethod));
        newThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        newThread.Start();
```

I used this as I kept getting an error on:

```
DialogResult result = browse.ShowDialog();
```

I believe the text isn't showing because it is in the new thread, but I don't get how it can still be used as if it were in the text box nor how to get the text to display.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

*EDIT*

[Web page viewed through Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StIT8.png)

The MCH Code text box is where the user will enter text. This is fine.
The selected file text box and the large one at the bottom is where I want text to be displayed.

I know it works as I have another text box with visibility set to false that gets added to, and then that text boxe's text is added into an SQL query so it is not blank and I add to this text box the same way as the others:
tb_Textbox.Text += "My text here"

Comment: you have a windows forms application that is writing to textboxes in an asp.net application...is that right?...I ask because I'm seeing a mixture of desktop and web concepts

Comment: I am creating a Web Application, I don't believe it is using any of windows form, potential solutions I saw before suggested using BeginInvoke but this would flag errors every time regardless of having System.Windows.Forms imported. The C# is being used for functionality in the Default.aspx.cs class, this is using the text boxes and button added through the design of the web page. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Why are you using a thread, are you executing an async call? What are you using to reload the UI, partial page updates using AJAX, a full page post-back?

Comment: @Paolis I am using a thread because without it I get this error:
"System.Threading.ThreadStateException: Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process." Which relates to the DialogResult line mentioned above. See this is my first go at a Web Application and all of the HTML/ASP that comes with it. I have set the text boxes to have AutoPostBack enabled which I led myself to believe is what would refresh the it

Comment: @R.Steele, I'm starting to agree with the above that you may be mixing desktop and web concepts, you shouldn't have a Main() function for a .NET web application. Are you using Visual Studio, if so what type of project did you select when starting this one?

Comment: @Paolis, I see, might have to look into alternative ways to do this then.
I am using Visual Studio and I selected Web Application when creating a new project. The functionality works it's just the text itself doesn't show.

Comment: @R.Steele, my main experience is with MVC these days and my Web Forms is outdated. I hope you're able to find out what the issue is., but from what I recall Threading should only be used when you are attempting to either implement certain async methods or implementing multithreading (which has limited use cases in most web applications). Since you have autopost back set on the Textboxes I'm assuming you aren't doing async calls, so you may want to first strip out using Threads and simplify your code to just get the Textboxes working as desired.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate you taking the time to help even if the question might not be relevant to the problem at hand!

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your objective, please correct me otherwise, are you trying to load data from the text boxes to the database on button click?

Comment: @SydneyKhanye This is what works, the text is technically in the text box and is being used in an SQL query later on. My problem is that text boxes aren't being updated visually for user feedback, such as; "Retrieving data for...", "Data got!" etc. So text can be used, but the boxes still appear blank.

Comment: If possible, could you share a snapshot of your GUI?

Comment: @SydneyKhanye see edits if that clears anything up.

Comment: Thanks that's better, so the data in textboxes will be appended to the list box at the bottom and from there on loaded to the sql database?